# Move background image from css to html using data-src (lazysizes) and use styles correctly

Tags: html, css

I have background images in my CSS file that are quite heavy. For that reason, I would like to load them using Lazysizes, which loads content as you scroll on my site.

[My github hosted page](https://bymw.github.io/)

To enable load on scroll the image needs to be inside the HTML using the class lazyload and data-src. This works very well for me on all the assets on the site but I have some background images in my CSS that I have tried to move over to the HTML, but I fail to style it and look and work the way the backgrounds currently does.

I did not write the entire CSS on the site and I'm stuck making the current background images act exactly like they do now, but give me the possibility to just have the image references in the HTML.

My attempts have resulted in the image being stretched or won't use the breaking points as all current backgrounds work with or the background resulting in a square in the middle of the page.

So the challange for me is not the actual HTML, or getting it to load using lazysizes. The challange is getting the CSS to work.. HTML element with the backgrounds I'm trying to change is attached below:

```html
<section class="proj">
      <hgroup>
        <h2>Socialmist</h2>
        <h6>Instagram with music from SoundCloud</h6>
      </hgroup>
      <div class="mw by full">
        <img class="wide">
      </div>
    </section>
```

Thank you for taking your time, much appreciated!

Comment: giving a runnable snippet that illustrates your issue, alongside with the related `CSS` code would really help us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work. Attached code below.

```css
.yay {
  max-height          : 550px;
  background-repeat   : no-repeat;
  background-position : center;
  object-fit          : cover;
}
```

```html
    <section class="proj">
      <hgroup>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h6>Placeholder</h6>
      </hgroup>
      <div>
        <img class="wide lazyload yay" data-src="img/sm/bg/7T5C5861-s.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </section>
```